# I'm trying to get words to print properly on each line in Python

Tags: python, formatting

I am running some Python code and the strings (words) are printing part of their word on each new line.
So I'm looking to find a way where on each new line, the strings display the full word, and not part word as it currently displays.
Example code below:

print("First line of text with various words that make up a long sentence which does not wrap\n")

sleep(3)

print("Second line of text, again with a long sentence, probably longer than the first which does not wrap words on second line when printed.\n")

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Are you looking for [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html)?

Comment: Thanks, example code added to my post.

Comment: @OllieP Did you try using `textwrap` with something like `for line in textwrap.wrap(text, width=50): print(line)`?

Comment: I took a look at the textwrap module thanks Matthias, but found I needed to add a lot of code changes once that library was imported to do what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which was to use the triple speechmarks:

print("""First line of text with various words that make up a long sentence which does not wrap\n""")

sleep(3)

print("""Second line of text, again with a long sentence, probably longer than the first which does not wrap words on second line when printed.\n""")

Answer (score 0):

You could try to flush your print output

```
print("First [...] wrap\n", flush=True)

sleep(3)

print("Second [...] printed.\n", flush=True)
```